# Loading data using sqlloader

Tags: shell, unix, sql-loader

I am trying to load data from flat file to the table. But flat file has LF(linefeed) so for every LF, one empty row is getting inserted into the table. 
Tried using some commands like trim, replace and others none of them are working here, Could anyone please help.
**sample flat file**
**test.txt**
ID NAME 
1  abc
2  def
(linefeed)
3  hij
(linefeed)
(linefeed)
4  klm
**control file**
**test.ctl**
`OPTIONS (SKIP=1)`
`LOAD DATA`
 `CHARACTERSET WE8ISO8859P1 length semantics char`
`TRUNCATE`
`INTO TABLE test`
`TRAILING NULLCOLS`  
`(  ID  char(4) ,`
 `NAME char(18))`
**command used**
`sqlldr CONTROL=test.ctl log=test.log data=test.txt USERID=appdata/app@orcl direct=true`
**table data**
| ID| NAME |
| --| -- |
| 1 | abc|
| 2 | def|
| NULL| NULL|
| 3 | hij|
| NULL| NULL|
| NULL| NULL|
| 4| klm| 

While loading data to the table i need to avoid these empty row to be inserted into the table.

Comment: Unix files have a single LF at the end.  On Windows, it is CR-LF.  If you must convert from one tot he other, `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` do that.

Comment: Make the data source fix their garbage before sending it to you! Don't accept their crap! Stop the insanity! I know, one has to allow for the garbage. I'm just sick of dealing with the same stupid problems for the last 30 years. Why haven't we learned yet!? Who's not doing their job teaching the next generation to have some pride in their work and clean it up before sending! OK, I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a free text editor, which contains following command in the Edit menu:

[image: Notepad++ screenshot]